# How do I make an iframe height 100% of it's content not based on aspect ratio using css?

Tags: html, css, iframe, pardot

I have an iframe containing a form that is dynamic. Lot of guides show how to make it change height based on a static aspect ratio but the form content changes so that doesn't work.

Is there a way using css to make an iframe or an iframe container 100% the height of it's content?

here's what I currently have but no changes of the height make a difference except static pixel values:

```
<style>
    .iframe_form_container {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        height: 100px;
    }
    .iframe_form {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 0px;
    }
</style>
<div class="iframe_form_container">
    <iframe src="*url*" width="100%" id="iframe_form" class="iframe_form" type="text/html" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can find the only solution is javascript. It's not a great user experience though.

[This guys built an iFrame resizing program that seems to work](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer)